# Java code not running?

Tags: java, cmd

I've been trying to compile java programs, and every single time these errors show up:

[image]

I'm compiling using cmd, and `javac test.java` works fine, returning no errors, but `java test` is resulting in the string of errors. What is the problem?

EDIT:
Here is the result of `javac -version` and `java -version`.

[image]

Comment: seems, you have set your classpath correctly

Comment: Please post the stack trace as an actual text instead of an image.

Comment: Please post complete error.

Comment: post complete snapshot of command prompt

Comment: I added snapshot of full command prompt window. The problem is not solved.

Comment: Seems like the file name differs in case from the class name.

Comment: Don't post screenshots here. Complete waste of everybody's bandwidth. It would have been just as easy to post the exception text. And what part of 'wrong name: Test' don't you understand?

Comment: Can you post codes for the same?

Answer (score 1):

> wrong name: Test

Your `Test` class is defined in a package but you didn't provide its package name on the command line.

Comment: Is Java case-sensitive on Windows?

Comment: From the log it is clear that the class name inside of test.java file is defined as Test not test and Java has nothing to do with windows. A class file should begin with capital letter this is a convention but however in your case you should either change the class name inside the file (class test) or rename the file to Test.java & compile with javac and then run with java cmd.

Answer (score 0):

To run a java program from the command-line, you need to consider the following:

1. Specify the fully qualified name of the main class you want to run, i.e.:

```
java com.somepackage.MainClass
```

2. Add the main class plus any dependent classes/jars to the classpath.

   - See: [Setting the Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: I'm just trying to run a simple 'hello world' program I wrote in notepad.

Comment: @AGZuniverse Then, most likely `java -cp . com.somepackage.MainClass` would work.

Answer (score -1):

Try running these commands with cmd:

```
javac -version
java -version
```

If one of them is not set properly you won't see your JDK version so you have to set right your environment variables.

Comment: I added the screenshot of this in the question. Please help!

Comment: @AGZuniverse Your environment variables are ok. I think your problem is that you are not using the full package of the class i.e. If your class is on `package code` then you should use `java code.test`. Be sure you are using .class and not .java. Good luck.